# SQL multiple table subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know why but I am unable to comprehend it. I've got two tables:

```
mysql> select * from PETICIONES;                                                                                             +--------+------------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| ID_PET | FECHA_PET  | ID_ANA | DNI_PAC   | DNI_DOC   |
+--------+------------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|      1 | 2008-01-03 |      2 | 71515623A | 23456398F |
|      2 | 2008-05-10 |      2 | 33788976F | 55776898K |
|      3 | 2008-05-08 |      3 | 79876867X | 23456398F |
|      4 | 2008-05-11 |      4 | 44787345H | 55776898K |
|      5 | 2008-05-12 |      2 | 19887234W | 25349857H |
|      6 | 2008-05-05 |      4 | 22897576R | 55776898K |
|      7 | 2008-03-15 |      5 | 44787345H | 88647389P |
|      8 | 2008-03-19 |      1 | 71515623A | 23456398F |
|      9 | 2008-03-26 |      2 | 71515623A | 78988484B |
|     10 | 2008-03-15 |      2 | 19887234W | 88647389P |
|     11 | 2008-03-15 |      3 | 33788976F | 55776898K |
|     12 | 2008-03-26 |      2 | 44787345H | 23456398F |
+--------+------------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

and

```
mysql> select * from TIPOS_ANALISIS;
+--------+-----------------+
| ID_ANA | DESC_ANA        |
+--------+-----------------+
|      1 | SANGRE BÁSICO   |
|      2 | SANGRE COMPLETO |
|      3 | ORINA BÁSICO    |
|      4 | ORINA COMPLETO  |
|      5 | HECES BÁSICO    |
|      6 | HECES COMPLETO  |
+--------+-----------------+
```

Now, all I've got to do is to find an analysis that was ordered the most and display it's details. Now I can find analysis that was ordered more times than others but to join these two tables so I can display it's description is something I am not doing too well with. I've tried this but it just trows an error and I can't sort it out (the error is: Operand should contain 1 column(s) ):

```
Select * from TIPOS_ANALISIS
    -> where ID_ANA = ( SELECT ID_ANA, COUNT(ID_ANA) as AnaCount
    -> from PETICIONES
    -> group by ID_ANA
    -> order by AnaCount DESC
    -> limit 1);
```

Could someone help and explain a bit? Please?

And what if I wanted to display number of counts? How do I do that?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: all good and all that but it's my practice database and I am trying to understand some concepts. Obviously I did read the theory on it and all, but  obviously have some difficulty with getting a hang of things. Oh, and I do appreciate that it my be very easy and not worth their time querry for some but as I am just starting out with SQL myself it doesn't seem that easy. With time I belive it will but I'm just not quite there yet. And I dare to belive there are many like me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select a.*
from TIPOS_ANALISIS a
where a.ID_ANA = (select p.ID_ANA
                  from PETICIONES p
                  group by p.ID_ANA
                  order by AnaCount DESC
                  limit 1
                 );
```

The error is that the subquery is a *scalar* subquery, meaning that it has to return one column and at most one row.  A scalar subquery is used in place of a constant value in SQL.

I'm not 100% sure this will work in MySQL.  MySQL is finicky about `limit` in certain subqueries.

But, you can just more this to the `from` clause:

```
Select a.*, p.AnaCount
from TIPOS_ANALISIS a join
    (select p.ID_ANA, count(*) as AnaCount
     from PETICIONES p
     group by p.ID_ANA
     order by AnaCount DESC
     limit 1
    ) p
    on a.ID_ANA = p.ID_ANA
```

Comment: What is AnaCount?

Comment: Thanks, after small tweaking the second one worked and I think I get why it works. So really appreaciated. Will try to figure the rest out mysel (if I can).

Comment: @Christian hey you can see in select p.ID_ANA, count (*) as AnaCount it's just like a variable but beware if you do a from table as t you can't access the name table anymore it's changed to t for this query :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
Select a.*
from TIPOS_ANALISIS a
where a.ID_ANA = (select b.ID_ANA
                  from PETICIONES b
                  group by b.ID_ANA
                  order by count(*) DESC
                  limit 1
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's already telling you that there should be only 1 column. Just select 1 column from your inner query:

```
Select * from TIPOS_ANALISIS
where ID_ANA = (SELECT ID_ANA FROM ( SELECT ID_ANA, COUNT(ID_ANA) as AnaCount
from PETICIONES
group by ID_ANA
order by AnaCount DESC
limit 1) t1);

#Edit: To display counts as well

SELECT ID_ANA, COUNT(ID_ANA) AS count from TIPOS_ANALISIS
    WHERE ID_ANA = (SELECT ID_ANA FROM ( SELECT ID_ANA, COUNT(ID_ANA) as AnaCount
from PETICIONES
    group by ID_ANA
    order by AnaCount DESC limit 1) t1)
GROUP BY ID_ANA;
```

Comment: And if I wanted to display the number of counts, how do I go about it?

Comment: Reply added to original answer

Answer (score 0):

You should select only ID_ANA from subselect

```
select * from TIPOS_ANALISIS 
where ID_ANA = ( SELECT ID_ANA 
                 from PETICIONES 
                 group by ID_ANA
                 order by COUNT(ID_ANA)
                 limit 1)
```